# Want to change the font of text

Tags: css, text, fonts, webfonts

I currently have this code:

```
 <div class="box" style="margin-bottom: 10px; max-width: 100%;">     
 <div class="clearfix"style="padding: 10px 10px 0 10px; background: #f3f3f3; text-align: center;">                <span style="font-size: 1.17em; color: #000000;">LINGERIE</span><br/>     
 <p style="color: #000000;">&nbsp;</p>
 <span style="color: #000000;">&diams;Lingerie Sets &nbsp; &nbsp;&diams;Hosiery &nbsp; &nbsp;                    &diams;Plus Size </span><span style="font-size: 12px;">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span></div>
</div>
```

Im unsure where to add my font? I would like to use Montserrat, which is the current font of my menu, ect. Thanks in advance

Comment: Inline CSS is bad practice. You should create a separate CSS file and include it within your HTML document's `head` with the `link` element.

Comment: Why is it 'bad practice' Thankyou

Comment: Because when you have multiple HTML files you're going to find it very difficult to maintain your styling. With CSS you can simply `div { margin-bottom: 10px; }` to apply that style to *all* `div` elements. With inline CSS, you'd instead have to re-write that every time you added the example `div` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS:

```
font-family: Montserrat;
```

for example:

```
<span style="color: #000000;font-family: Montserrat;">&diams;Lingerie Sets ...</span>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp

Answer (score 0):

In [this link](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Montserrat) you have a full explanation about how to use the Montserrat font:

1) Add this code to your website (add it into your `<head>` section of your html page):

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

2) Create a new file i.e. `styles.css` and add it also yo your `<head>` section (or reuse an old one). Then integrate your fonts into your CSS:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
```

Example:

```
h1 { 
    font-family: ‘Metrophobic’, Arial, serif; 
    font-weight: 400; 
}
```